# Virtual addresses managed by Android

Tags: ram

I have the following questions:

How Android map virtual addresses to physical addresses?
Does Android use virtual memory like desktop OS?
What is the replacement algorithm used by Android?

These questions are quite simple to Desktop OS's and there are a lot of books about it, but Android looks like a black box in a matter of these concepts.

There are three questions and answers to any of them are welcome.

Comment: Mapping virtual addresses to physical addresses is handled in kernel space, not by applications in userspace. Since Android uses Linux kernel (with some modifications), what's true for Linux is also true for Android. Going in depth, it's a development related question, off-topic here.